# How does react -native set the network request timeout time?

Tags: react-native

Fetch API in React Native. How to set the timeout time of the request, and I hope everyone can give a good suggestion. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Use Package : **whatwg-fetch-timeout**

[Package Link](https://www.npmjs.com/package/whatwg-fetch-timeout)

npm command :   `npm install whatwg-fetch-timeout --save;`

**Usage :**

```
return fetch('/path', {timeout: 500}).then(function() {
  // successful fetch
}).catch(function(error) {
  // network request failed / timeout
})
```

Comment: It's not a real fetch timeout (downside, react-native do request with okHttp or NSURLSession & whatwg-fetch-timeout does not override default timeout)